# Telegram chat ID changed

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I had a few group chats in Telegram with the same Telegram bot. I had an initial chat ID which was automatically changed these days to the new ID. Can anyone explain why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It only happens when a group is changed to a supergroup. Telegram sends an update informing you about this change, you should handle it.

Take a look "migrate_to_chat_id" field here.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#message